# Insert variable into jQuery offset

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have this variable:

```
var scrollYaxis = window.pageYOffset;
```

My actual code:

```
var productsTopPosition = $('#products').offset().top;
```

I would like to change this by using the variable value, how to I do this correct?

```
var productsTopPosition = $('#products').offset(scrollYaxis);
```

Which is the correct way to insert this using the `scrollYaxis` so the offset of `$('#products')` is applied?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? I'm seeing here some unexplained magic which is probably achieveable by `position: fixed`

Comment: @matewka I'm debugging a site seen on ipad. Position fixed turned into my enemy hehe But this has nothing to do with position:fixed. I'm trying to create a highlight of a menu when the scroll position is the same or lower than the Yscroll. Offset().top is giving me some bad results on ipad, so I'm trying with this method...

Answer (score 0):

You can  set the offset to a particular position using the following code

```
$( "p:last" ).offset({ top: 10, left: 30 });
```